# Python 2.7 regex with format multiple list items

Tags: python, regex, format

Imagine I want to find all time expressions referring to 'AM' and 'PM' in a string.  Let's ignore for the moment that I could use '[AP]M' to do this (because I'm actually pulling the list of valid strings ['AM','PM'] from a dictionary whose keys are language codes).  I'd like to look for both at once, like this:

```
foo = ['am','pm']
separator = ':'
timex = re.compile('(1[012]|[1-9])%s([0-5][0-9])( %s)?' % (separator, foo), re.I)

bar = "It's 6:00 pm, do you know where your brain is?"
```

timex as written above doesn't get me what I'm after:  it only matches to the 'p' in 'pm'.  (It seems to be treating all the chars of the list elements as though they were [ampm].)

What I don't want is to do two passes over the string (one each for 'am' and 'pm').

Is there a nice Pythonic way to do a single pass for every item in foo?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't do a check for (am|pm) in regex?

Comment: I'd like to avoid locale-specific expressions.  English uses am/pm, but Korean uses 오전/오후, Greek uses π.μ./μ.μ., etc.  I tried to simplify the code in my question for readability.  In actuality, foo would be something like ampms[locale], where ampms is a dictionary of locales to 2-element lists.

Comment: What does your result look like?

Comment: Did you try joining foo with | and then sticking it in the regex group then?

Comment: @AaronHall: timex.search(bar).group() yields '6:00 p'

Comment: what does your *desired* result look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the way I've inserted a list of arbitrary regex terms to be searched for:

```
import re

foo = ['am','pm']
timex = re.compile('({foo})'.format(foo='|'.join(foo)))

bar = "It's 6:00 pm, do you know where your brain is?"

timex.findall(bar)
```

returns

```
['pm']
```

You can capture more:

```
>>> timex = re.compile(r'(\d{{1,2}}:\d{{2}})\s*({foo})'.format(foo='|'.join(foo)))
>>> timex.findall(bar)
[('6:00', 'pm')]
```

Comment: Here it is reworked to be closer to the original:  timex = re.compile(r'(1[012]|[1-9]){}([0-5][0-9])\s*({})'.format(sep, '|'.join(foo)))